# Port forwarding for DVR - Enable Email service

Tags: email, port, forwarding

I've set up a cheap DVR with analog cameras that are available for access from the web, but I cannot set up the EMAIL service from the DVR - its used when a motion sensor gets triggered during non-operational times. When I get a prompt to set up the smtp client I cannot establish a connection to the mail server , I try SSL I try without SSL , 25 465 26 port and nothing... I tried to forward external port 465 to internal 34567 (which corresponds to the DVR when accessed by applications) and to internal 81 (which corresponds to the DVR when accessed by Web) and nothing... with port checker I can confirm that the ports are open but DVR keeps saying "failed to connect to server".

As a last resort attempted to set up a gmail account (instead of our own emails from our domain) and still no success.

I have a basic idea of how port forwarding works , the way I see things should happen is that when the DVR attempts to connect to the desired mail server , it sends packets thru a specific port and expects them to be received thru the same port on the server end, so I try to set up like so

465 465 192.168.222.110 ALL Enabled

25  25  192.168.222.110 ALL Enabled

222.110 - being the DVR

and again nothing...

I am open to any advice , as I am not very experienced in networking.

Comment: You don't need any port forwarding to send email. Can you take a screen shot of what the config options are for sending email in the DVR GUI?

Comment: https://images.vikremonti.info/config.png
This what it looks like

Comment: I would try using your email as the sender and if that does not work maybe try port 587. Or maybe even another email service as a test to see if it is the  firmware on the DVR.

Comment: Sender is with limited input - cant enter full email ....
port 587 with and without SSL returned the same error , 
I also tried using gmail service and it failed there as well so im starting to think that either the antenna our ISP provided has some firewall or that the DVR is faulty ....

Comment: Your ISP will more than likely have a SMTP relay you can use.

Comment: Nope , the dude made the antenna into Bridge mode in order to provide us with a static address to the router... there are no restrictions on their antenna. Well I guess its just the DVR than , deal with it we just wont get emails / push notifications... Thanks for the help though i was convinced I wasnt doing something right about these ports

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all then try upgrading the firmware of the DVR box some times it can happen due to bad firmware, **first take backup of current firmware**

you can also check if your local firewall or device is getting any request on ports you have mentioned when you try to test email

Mostly for outgoing there should be no issue in firewall, **you can check if your firewall has any application based filter which is not allowing your DVR box to send emails**

You can also check for date time on DVR

Comment: DVR not upgradable , disabled firewall on router , time and date are exact

Answer (score 0):

Your DVR will not be a mail server - it will simply hand email off to a SMTP relay for onwards forwarding, like you dropping a postcard in the mailbox instead of hand-delivering it to the recipient's mailbox.

Try telnetting to your mail relay or your ISP's mail relay from the DVR (if possible) or from another device in the same network range.

Could be connectivity problems, or authentication problems.

You do not need any NATs from the internet to the DVR for email.

---

Unrelated, but I'd advise not having any NATs at all from the internet to the DVR.  They're generally cheap nasty insecure devices with no ongoing security updates.  Instead, consider a good VPN from your remote device (laptop/phone) to your firewall, and then encrypt all traffic.